# HP Omen 15 and Linux

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, distributions

This is a simple question:
Is there anyone out there who has installed any Linux distro on a HP Omen 15 laptop and have it work to satisfaction. I couldn't find it amongst the certified units on Ubuntu's website and am therefore a bit worried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the latest 64 bit Puppy works great for me, but only as a dual-boot to Windows, since the Nvidia drivers for it suck and no keyboard/fan control. Should note that controls set up in Windows stick after booting to Linux, though. Battery life is top shelf, speed beats the pants off of Windows. The only real downside is the touchscreen is FUBAR on Puppy. May as well forget it's there. For productivity/writing/etc, it's amazing, but don't try to use it for gaming. If you want to game on this thing, dual boot Win7/8/10. As a refreshing side note, the issue with constant crashes on the Intel GPU doesn't happen on Puppy. I use it for work and pretty much only boot Win10 for games.